# How to make a form centered in flutter Widget?

Tags: flutter, forms

I need some help on my code, i have a form for registering but i cant seem to make it centered and button to below it,meaning set the height so there is little space in between the form and button. I just need to be shown from the given code where must i centered the form and make a below space for button. I also want my Textfield to be around-centered, i will appreciate this a lot.

// flutter form for registering users.

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // form fields
  String? _usernameError;
  String? _emailError;
  String? _passwordError;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Registration Page'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey, // Assign the key to the Form
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 265,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _usernameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    errorText: _usernameError,
                    errorStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // Set error text color
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      setState(() {
                        _usernameError = "Please enter a username";
                      });
                      return "Please enter a username";
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      _usernameError = null;
                    });
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 265,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    errorText: _emailError,
                    errorStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // Set error text color
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      setState(() {
                        _emailError = "Please enter your email address";
                      });
                      return "Please enter your email address";
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      _emailError = null;
                    });
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 265,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    errorText: _passwordError,
                    errorStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // Set error text color
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      setState(() {
                        _passwordError = "Please enter a password";
                      });
                      return "Please enter a password";
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      _passwordError = null;
                    });
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    _registerUser();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Register'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Spacer` above button to fill empty space, also add `SizedBox` below button, so it wont stick to bottom of the screen:

```
const Spacer(),
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    _registerUser();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Register'),
              ),
const SizedBox(height: 16),
```

Comment: thanks mate, do you know perhaps how can i centered my form in the middle?

Comment: Use `Center` widget, or add `alignment` property to `Container`